# How to get one active instance (Excel) when multiple instances are running?

Tags: vsto, office-addins, excel-addins

```
        Excel.Application instance = null;
        Workbook wb = null;
        //getting the current running instance of an excel application
        //note : only one instance should be running while using this addin
        //fix yet to be developed
        instance = (Excel.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");


        //instance = new Excel.Application();

        //opening the template
        wb = instance.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\ExcelAddin\Templates\sample.xltx");

        //selecting the first sheet1
        Excel.Worksheet ws = wb.Worksheets[1];
```

I have been trying to create an Add-in for Excel, I was successful in creating the whole Add-in but there is a bug in the code, it works only when one instance of Excel is running in the process but I know that is going to happen from the beginning.

How can I fix the bug so that my Add-in can work even if number instances of Excel application are open?

Comment: Please put *all* relevant information IN your question. There's more in that comment to a proposed Answer than is in the question. Comments are ephemeral - they can disappear at any time. You need to include a *lot* more detail about how this non-standard VSTO solution is structured! FWIW however Processes can get a list of all instances of an application. "Latching on" to one of them to work in the Interop is something else, altogether. Office applications register only ONE instance in the ROT - there is no "top-most instance" - this makes them difficult to interact with.

Comment: so, please tell me how the instances are handled when it comes to loading templates using macros and manipulating the documents created using those templates.i not a kind of person who bothers about the down vote as long as i can learn and get the answer from the community, Thanks for looking into my question

Comment: A VSTO add-in should load in EVERY instance of Excel that's started and has access to that instance. It's not clear why you're worried about numerous instances. Nor do you explain how the dll is being used, etc. There's simply no way anyone can offer reasonable advice based on the information you provide.

Comment: The dll has windows forms and the data will be saved into xml, then while selecting template the xml will be deserialized and the data will be filled automatically.i thought that holding the instance from the ROI would help me in manipulating the particular sheet in a way that i want,but its not working while more than 1 instance is open,i have shared the line of code above where the instance is handled and i thought that i can help people understand how i am thinking about the handling of instance, i don't see any need to share the rest of code because that has nothing to do with my problem

Answer (score 0):

To get the current Instance of Excel Application in AddIn Project, yoo can use

```
Excel.Application _ExcelApp = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application
Excel.Worksheet _Excelsheet =  (Excel.Worksheet)ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
```

We are using the same in Excel AddIn project and working with current instance using above code.

Comment: i'll implement it and give you the status, thanks a ton for the answer.

Comment: Sorry, This is not the answer that i was looking for, to put things in a simple way my addin will open a template and also the whole logic is inside of a dll apart from Add in and i didn't simply use the ThisAddin.cs file as i want a different navigation bar menu.

Comment: I have added one more line of code to show how i am manipulating data